# cuando intento hacer un efecto de aparición en un menú con :hover al pasar el ratón por el submenu ya no se queda visible

Tags: html5, css3

Intento hacer un submenu que se desplegué al hacer :hover sobre un ítem del menu, de hecho eso ya lo hace, pero cuando quiero bajar hacia el submenu este desaparece y ya no puedo seleccionar nada.

Código CSS:

```
.MenuUL {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.MenuIL {
    float: left;
}

.MenuIL a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.MenuIL a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.SubMenuUL {
    display:none;
}

#viewMore:hover + .SubMenuUL
{
    display:block
}
```

Código Html:

```
<ul class="MenuUL" >
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" id="idMenuInicio1" class="MenuFirst">Inicio</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Trabajos</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Acerca De</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Contacto</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Presupuesto</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst" id="viewMore">Ver Mas</a>
 <ul class="SubMenuUL" >
    <li>
        <a class="tagA" id="SubMenu1" href="#">Cv Online</a>
    </li>
</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Al pasar mi cursor si aparece el submenu, pero intentar pasar el cursor sobre el submenu desaparece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira esto puede servirte

**CSS**

```html
<style>
.MenuUL {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
.MenuIL {
    float: left;
}
.MenuIL a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.MenuIL a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.SubMenuUL {
    background-color: #111;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
#viewMore:hover + .SubMenuUL {
    display:block
}
.SubMenuUL:hover {
    display:block
}
</style>

<ul class="MenuUL" >
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" id="idMenuInicio1" class="MenuFirst">Inicio</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Trabajos</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Acerca De</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Contacto</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst">Presupuesto</a></li>
  <li class="MenuIL"><a href="#" class="MenuFirst" id="viewMore">Ver Mas</a>
 <ul class="SubMenuUL" >
    <li>
        <a class="tagA" id="SubMenu1" href="#">Cv Online</a>
    </li>
</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Asigne una posicion fija a la caja a mostrar y un fondo

```
.SubMenuUL {
        background-color: #111;
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
    }
```

También agregue el `:hover` de la caja

```
.SubMenuUL:hover {
    display:block
}
```

Saludos :)